# Cloud SDK: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

When I run the command:

```
gcloud projects list
```

I get warnings:

```
google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\lib\third_party\urllib3\connectionpool.py:986: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'oauth2.googleapis.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning,
google-cloud-sdk\bin\..\lib\third_party\urllib3\connectionpool.py:986: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made to host 'cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com'. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings
  InsecureRequestWarning,
```

I use Cloud SDK on Windows 10.

What these warnings mean and how to fix them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are warnings not errors.

They warn that the client (`gcloud`) isn't verifying the certificate(s) (hopefully being) received from Google. The client isn't verifying the certificate(s) certifying chain which proves the authenticity of the cert(s) and thus it's possible the certs that are received aren't the ones issued to Google, hence the warning.

This may (not) being done by`gcloud` to avoid problems with corporate SSL proxies which can terminate SSL connections to monitor traffic.

`gcloud projects list` uses 2 Google APIs `oauth2` to authenticate you and `cloudresourcemanager` to list the projects. Other commands will throw different numbers of this warning for different sets of APIs being used.

You may be able to configure Python or `urllib3` to stop showing the warning **but** I'd recommend leaving it as-is.